# Delphi 2007 - ASP.net - Window already registered as a drop target / Failed to Find Event

Tags: asp.net, delphi, windows-7, delphi-2007, delphi.net

I have a large ASP.net project that I need to maintain in Delphi 2007.  When I open any ASP.net project, including a Hello World project, I immediately get an error message saying "This window has already been registered as a drop target.". I get this message as soon as the project is opened in the IDE.  When I attempt to access an object event (an on-click event for a button for example) I get an error message saying "Failed to find event".

I have a Windows 7 professional (32 bit) machine that is fully patched.  I have the same problem at home with an XP Proffesional (SP3) machine that is fully patched.  We have several developers that all have the same problem.

Has anybody else seen this problem or know of any steps for troubleshooting?  Nothing of interest shows up in the Windows event logs.  Another thing I noticed is that I can no longer change the button text or size...changes are not made to the underlying .aspx file when I make the changes in design mode.  The error details are a little lengthy as follows:

Drop target error details:

```
[2004474C]{rtl100.bpl  } ComObj.OleError (Line 1269, "common\ComObj.pas" + 1) + $11
[2004475B]{rtl100.bpl  } ComObj.OleCheck (Line 1276, "common\ComObj.pas" + 0) + $7
[070A5945]{htmide100.bpl} HTMLBaseFrame.EnableMultipleSelection (Line 740, "HTMLBaseFrame.pas" + 1) + $2A
[070A5B1A]{htmide100.bpl} HTMLBaseFrame.THTMLBaseFrameWindow.InitializeDocumentEditingOptions (Line 791, "HTMLBaseFrame.pas" + 32) + $1
[07A7ADD6]{dotnetaspide100.bpl} ASPEditorFrm.TASPEditorFrame.InitializeViewLinkDocumentEditingOptions (Line 1821, "ASPEditorFrm.pas" + 1) + $18
[07A7AD1E]{dotnetaspide100.bpl} ASPEditorFrm.TASPEditorFrame.InitializeViewLinkDocumentsEditingOptions (Line 1806, "ASPEditorFrm.pas" + 8) + $8
[07A7AC96]{dotnetaspide100.bpl} ASPEditorFrm.TASPEditorFrame.InitializeLoadedDocumentEditingOptions (Line 1789, "ASPEditorFrm.pas" + 4) + $9
[070A5C4D]{htmide100.bpl} HTMLBaseFrame.THTMLBaseFrameWindow.WebBrowserEx1DocumentComplete (Line 857, "HTMLBaseFrame.pas" + 46) + $4
[07A7C9C9]{dotnetaspide100.bpl} ASPEditorFrm.TASPEditorFrame.WebBrowserEx1DocumentComplete (Line 2518, "ASPEditorFrm.pas" + 15) + $B
[201CC182]{vcl100.bpl  } OleCtrls.TOleControl.InvokeEvent (Line 1612, "OleCtrls.pas" + 46) + $0
[4080756A]{vcliex100.bpl} WebBrowserEx.TWebBrowserEx.InvokeEvent (Line 2583, "WebBrowserEx.pas" + 1) + $4
[201C9D6B]{vcl100.bpl  } OleCtrls.TEventDispatch.Invoke (Line 471, "OleCtrls.pas" + 3) + $9
[201625E8]{vcl100.bpl  } Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 8103, "Forms.pas" + 21) + $1
[2016262A]{vcl100.bpl  } Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage (Line 8124, "Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[2016291F]{vcl100.bpl  } Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 8223, "Forms.pas" + 20) + $3
[0042297A]{bds.exe     } bds.bds (Line 195, "" + 7) + $7
```

///////////////

Failed to find event details:

```
[21E2C06F]{dotnetcoreide100.bpl} DotNetPropInsp.TDotNetProperty.Edit (Line 891, "DotNetPropInsp.pas" + 1) + $39
[2000A455]{rtl100.bpl  } System.@CheckAutoResult (Line 18047, "sys\system.pas" + 6) + $0
[21E2C06F]{dotnetcoreide100.bpl} DotNetPropInsp.TDotNetProperty.Edit (Line 891, "DotNetPropInsp.pas" + 1) + $39
[20AB55BC]{coreide100.bpl} PropInsp.TPropertyInspector.PropListEditDblClick (Line 853, "PropInsp.pas" + 18) + $1C
[20E0ED7D]{vclide100.bpl} IDEInspListBox.TInspListBox.DoEditDblClick (Line 967, "ideinsplistbox.pas" + 2) + $A
[20E10602]{vclide100.bpl} IDEInspListBox.TInspListBox.EditDblClick (Line 1538, "ideinsplistbox.pas" + 0) + $2
[2013CA49]{vcl100.bpl  } Controls.TControl.DblClick (Line 5234, "Controls.pas" + 1) + $14
[2013CBAC]{vcl100.bpl  } Controls.TControl.WMLButtonDblClk (Line 5275, "Controls.pas" + 4) + $C
[2013C527]{vcl100.bpl  } Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 5146, "Controls.pas" + 83) + $6
[2132827C]{vclactnband100.bpl} ActnMenus.CallWndHook (Line 703, "ActnMenus.pas" + 12) + $F
[201406A7]{vcl100.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 7304, "Controls.pas" + 111) + $6
[2003203C]{rtl100.bpl  } Classes.TThreadList.UnlockList (Line 3359, "common\Classes.pas" + 0) + $4
[200EBAA8]{vcl100.bpl  } Graphics.FreeMemoryContexts (Line 5060, "Graphics.pas" + 12) + $5
(0002E348){CnWizards_D11.dll} [080EF348]
[20140158]{vcl100.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.IsControlMouseMsg (Line 7176, "Controls.pas" + 9) + $25
[201406A7]{vcl100.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 7304, "Controls.pas" + 111) + $6
[20E0DF4B]{vclide100.bpl} IDEInspListBox.TPropInspEdit.WndProc (Line 430, "ideinsplistbox.pas" + 7) + $4
[2013FDD0]{vcl100.bpl  } Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 7073, "Controls.pas" + 3) + $6
[20040E4C]{rtl100.bpl  } Classes.StdWndProc (Line 11583, "common\Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
[20163691]{vcl100.bpl  } Forms.TApplication.StopHintTimer (Line 8673, "Forms.pas" + 3) + $6
[201625E8]{vcl100.bpl  } Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 8103, "Forms.pas" + 21) + $1
[2016262A]{vcl100.bpl  } Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage (Line 8124, "Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[2016291F]{vcl100.bpl  } Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 8223, "Forms.pas" + 20) + $3
[0042297A]{bds.exe     } bds.bds (Line 195, "" + 7) + $7
```

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you have Delphi8 to maintain your ASP.NET application? If that is the case you will need to take a look at Delphi Prism. Delphi8/.Net is dead...

Comment: Which build number of Delphi 2007 do you have (in Help/About) ? The IDE itself is incredibly buggy, and similar issues for us were resolved by updating it.

Comment: It has been a long time since this question was opened. Was a solution ever found?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I encountered this problem exact problem when I did not have my ldap servers configured in my config file.

Adding the correct ldap servers to my `AppSettings.config` resolved the problem for me.